# How do I tell a javascript variable that it can't be undefined, at its creation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
getPersonneById(id: number): Personne{
    const personne = this.personnes.find( personne => {
      return personne.id == id;
    });
    return personne;
}
```

It shows this error : Impossible to assign type 'Person | undefined' to type 'Person'.
Impossible to assign type 'undefined' to type 'Person'.

I also did this one and it worls but that's not what I really want:

```
getPersonneById(id: number): Personne{
    const personne = this.personnes.find( personne => {
      return personne.id == id;
    });
    if(typeof personne !== 'undefined'){
      return personne;
    }else{
      return this.personnes['0'];
    }
}
```

personnes is an array.

So what I want to know is if there is a way to tell to my var that it couldn't be undefined or some better solution

Comment: `getPersonneById(id: number): Personne | undefined {`

Comment: The problem is that the id might not be in the list, which is why personne is of type `Person | undefined`. See the bot answer for your possible solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that a value will always be found by `find`, use the [non-null  assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to express that guarantee in TypeScript:

```
return personne!;
```